# Showing ajax Django error

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am working on a Django project that contains a lot of ajax calls.
Since i am still developing my website the ajax call sometimes return an Django error, but since these error's are formatted in HTML they are almost impossible read.
Is there any way that i easily read the ajax error's, like opening them in a new tab?

Comment: Would it not be easier to try and catch exception in your views and return sensible errors instead of html django errors?

Comment: with Firefox/Firebug and newer Chrome versions you can also view the response of an ajax request as formatted HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the ajax calls are send with jquery you can try this:

```
$("body").ajaxError(function(a,xhr,c) {
    $("body").append(
        $("<div style=\"width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:99999;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:#FFF\">")
        .html(xhr.responseText)
        .dblclick(function(){$(this).remove()})
    )
});
```

This will fetch all ajax error's and put them into a div. (you can remove the error by dubble clicking the error div)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use the development tools in your browser, like Firebug for Firefox or Safari's Development Tools. They list all the HTTP calls within a page, and if Firebug's been updated yet, it should show the error as a formatted HTML page.i find that easier than trapping errors and displaying them in JavaScript